# Como actualizar una variable asíncrona en la vista en angular?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular4

mi código del componente es el siguiente:

```js
conectado: boolean;
seleccionarDispositivos(): void {
  funcion() { \\Esta es mi función asíncrona
    ... \\Código asíncrono
    if(...) {
      this.conectado = true;
    } else {
      this.conectado = false;
    }
  }
}
```

mi código del html es el siguiente:

```html
<button type="button" (click)="seleccionarDispositivos()" class="btn btn-default">
Seleccionar dispositivo
</button>
{{conectado}}
```

¿Como puedo hacer que la variable conectado este siempre sincronizada? Cada vez que pulso el botón seleccionar dispositivo me muestra siempre el valor anterior y no el actual. 
Es curioso porque si llamo a otra función del componente entre medias si que se me actualiza el valor en el html, si no me muestra el anterior.

Answer (score 1):

#### Opción 1

Lo más probable que tu función asíncrona como describes no esté actuando sobre el DOM de Angular, es decir, no le está avisando a Angular que debe de renderizar de nuevo.

Hay varios métodos para hacer (forzar) qué Angular renderize de nuevo la/s vistas, te expongo 3:

> Utilizando **setTimeout** o **setInterval** Angular siempre volverá a renderizar.
>
> Utilizar la clase **ChangeDetectorRef** que proporciona Angular en su core para llamar al método *detectChanges()* para que renderize.

Mi recomendación es [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef), y si este no te funciona tirar del clásico setTimeout.

#### Opción 2

Puedes hacer que tu propiedad conectada sea reactiva con [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md).

> Typescript

```
conectado = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

seleccionarDispositivos(): void {
  // Código...
  if (/* ... */) {
    this.conectado.next(true);
  } else {
    this.conectado.next(false);
  }
}
```

> HTML

```
{{ conectado | async }}
```